# Java vs Objective-c UTF-8 Encoding

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, xcode, utf-8

I need to translate java code to objective-c, but I'm stuck in a string to byte array conversion.

In java I have:

```
String Key="1234567890";
byte[] xKey = Key.getBytes();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(xKey));
```

And it prints:

```
[49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 48]
```

And in objective-c I have:

```
NSString *Key = @"1234567890";
(1) NSData * xKey = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
(2) NSLog(@"%@", xKey);
```

and it prints:

```
<31323334 3536373839 30>
```

In (1) I've used:

```
const char * xKey = [Key UTF8String];
```

and in (2) I've used:

```
NSLog(@"%@s", xKey);
```

In UTF-8 48 corresponds to 0.

Comment: Can you give more context regarding why you want to have your `NSLog` output look like Android's `println`?

Comment: I need to compare that both outputs be the same to go further in the rest of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct UTF-8 encoded form of the `String` `"1234567890"` is simply the codes of its characters because all are encoded using 1 byte (their codes are less than 127):

```
[49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 48]
```

Note: [`Arrays.toString(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-byte:A-) uses the decimal representation of the bytes to construct the `String` representation of the array.

If you look closer, the Objective-c result **is exactly the same**, it's just printed in hexadecimal radix:

```
<31323334 3536373839 30>
```

> 0x31 = 49
>   0x32 = 50
>   ...
>   0x30 = 48

By the way [`String.getBytes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes--) qutoing from the javadoc:

> Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the **platform's default charset**, storing the result into a new byte array.

So the platform's default encoding is used, so the result may change from platform-to-platform, so it's always recommended to state in which encoding you want the result, e.g.:

```
byte[] xKey = Key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
byte[] xKey = Key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: The problem is not java. And using this returns the same (49, 50, ....). But thank you